# postgreSQL 1 minute average of values

Tags: sql, postgresql, average

I need to query from my database (postgreSQL) the value average of 1 minute.

The database is recorded in milliseconds and looks like this:

```
timestamp | value
------------------
1528029265001 | 123
1528029265020 | 232
1528029265025 | 332
1528029265029 | 511
...           | ...
1528029265176 | 231
```

I tried:

```
SELECT   
      avg(value), 
      extract(minutes FROM to_timestamp(timestamp/1000)) as one_min
FROM table GROUP BY one_min
```

But it seems to be stuck in querying.

I'm sure there is a super easy way to do it.
Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean "stuck in querying"?

Comment: it is loading forever..

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you want:

```
SELECT floor(timestamp/(60 * 1000)) as timestamp_minute
       avg(value)
FROM table
GROUP BY timestamp_minute;
```

However, if your problem is performance, this will have the same performance issues.  For that, you would want a `where` clause that limits the amount of data being processed.

Because the data is not being collected at even intervals, you might want the simple average of the first and last values, or something like that.

Comment: how is floor making one minute intervalrs ?

Comment: @DanielBaeriswyl . . . It does when the division is correct.